# How to make CSS transformation scale affects other elements?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Is  it possible to pin the "text" (div class="move") to growing "click on me" and move it up and down together with growing "click on me" (div id="click")?

Is it possible to keep the width of element "click on me" (div id="click") 100% during the transformation?

```css
.first_div {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

.first_div p {
 font: 30px arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 0.77em;
    color: #222;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
   100% {
        transform: scale(4,4);
   }
}

#click {
    animation: my-animation 5s linear forwards;
    transform-origin: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_div">
       <div class="move">
            <p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text<br>
            dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
       </div>
   <div id="click" href="#"><a href="#second_div">click on me</a></div>
       <div class="move">
        <p>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text<br>
           dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text</p>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use mouse hover

Comment: That's a plan B.

Comment: Sure... **don't use a transform** it's an *entirely* visual effect.